# how to save form data as it is entered shiny app r

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a database program with local file storage. I want to save form entries in a temporary variable and associated temporary file before the sumbit button (goButton) is clicked (so a user can come back if the window gets closed). This is for a single user. Questions: 1) why does the script record the last input (name) and a blank entry for id when both fields have text entered (but the button is not pressed)? 2) is there a way to monitor mutliple inputs without having to wire and observe for each one (the real code has 100+ fields)?

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

# on first run uncomment below and run
    # temp <- list(id = numeric(), name=character())
    # saveRDS(temp,"temp.rds")

#import table data
mydata <- as.data.table(readRDS("mydata.rds"))

# read temp file
temp <- readRDS("temp.rds")
temp

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(dataTableOutput("table"), # datatable here
               # form inputs
               numericInput(inputId ='id', label = 'Enter new ID', value =temp$id), 
               textInput(inputId ='name', label = 'Enter new name', value = temp$name),
               actionButton(inputId ="goButton", label = "Update Table"))

server <- function(input,output, session){
  # when user submits form, delete temp file. 
  observeEvent(input$goButton,{
    temp <- list(id = numeric(), name=character())
    saveRDS(temp, "temp.rds")
    temp
    # updateTextInput()
  })

  # save form data as its entered
  observeEvent(input$id, {
    temp$id <- input$id
    saveRDS(temp, "temp.rds")

  })
  observeEvent(input$name, {
    temp$name <- input$name
    saveRDS(temp, "temp.rds")

  })

  # DT output 
  output$table <- renderDataTable(df())
  # update datatable 
  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    if(input$id !="" && !(input$id %in% unique(mydata$id)) && input$goButton>0){
      newrow = data.table(id = input$id,
                          val = input$name)
      mydata <<- rbind(mydata, newrow)
    }else{ 
      if(input$id !="" && (input$id %in% unique(mydata$id)) && input$goButton>0){
        mydata[id==input$id, val := input$name]
        mydata <<- mydata
      }
    }
    saveRDS(mydata,"mydata.rds")
    mydata
    #write report

  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: To help with your second problem you could saves the variables the user has already entered to the temp.rds using `reactive`

Comment: care to share an reactive example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the "<<-" arrow to change temp in your observers.

```
  observeEvent(input$goButton,{
    temp <<- list(id = numeric(), name=character())
    saveRDS(temp, "temp.rds")
    temp
    # updateTextInput()
  })
  observeEvent(input$id, {
    temp$id <<- input$id
    saveRDS(temp, "temp.rds")

  })
  observeEvent(input$name, {
    temp$name <<- input$name
    saveRDS(temp, "temp.rds")

  })
```

Otherwise, each time you fill in a field, the temp.rds file is overwritten with the temp object, where only one value has been stored.